# How can I show multiple distinct fields in a column from the same table when using group in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I have a Ruby on Rails application that displays vehicle recall information. In my view, I have a table with 4 columns: Recall #, Vehicle, Description, Type. This view is populated from one model, one controller and one table. There are many repeating recall numbers with different vehicles however the description and type are the same. For example:

```
Recall # | Vehicle       | Description       | Type
---------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
2014020  | Kenworth C500 | Lorem ipsum dolor | Safety Mfr
2014020  | Kenworth C550 | Lorem ipsum dolor | Safety Mfr
2014020  | Kenworth T170 | Lorem ipsum dolor | Safety Mfr
```

In the view (index.html.erb), I'm trying to display the data with one recall number, many vehicles, one description and one type, like:

```
Recall # | Vehicle       | Description       | Type
---------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
2014020  | Kenworth C500 | Lorem ipsum dolor | Safety Mfr
         | Kenworth C550 |                   | 
         | Kenworth T170 |                   | 
---------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
```

But I can't seem to get code in `index.html.erb` right. Using the code below in my index, I get:

```
Recall # | Vehicle       | Description       | Type
---------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
2014020  | Kenworth C500 | Lorem ipsum dolor | Safety Mfr
         | Kenworth C550 |                   | 
         | Kenworth T170 |                   | 
         | Kenworth C500 |                   |
         | Kenworth C550 |                   |
         | Kenworth T170 |                   |
         | Kenworth C500 |                   |
         | Kenworth C550 |                   |
         | Kenworth T170 |                   |
---------|---------------|-------------------|-----------
```

The block of code in my view for Vehicle is:

```
<% for recall in @recalls.where(:recall_num => rn.recall_num) %>
  <%= recall.vehicle %><br>
<% end %>
```

How can I change the view to return distinct vehicles? Or would it be better to put the code in the controller? By better, I mean a performance improvement in the view rendering.

**View: index.html.erb**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @group_by_recallnum.each do |rn| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to rn.recall_num, "http://localhost&rn=#{rn.recall_num}" %></td>
        <td>
          <% for recall in @recalls.where(:recall_num => rn.recall_num) %>
            <%= recall.vehicle %><br>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= rn.description %></td>
        <td><%= rn.recall_type %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**Model: recall.rb**

```
class Recall < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**Controller: recalls_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @recalls = Recall.all
  @group_by_recallnum = @recalls.group(:recall_num).order('recall_num DESC') 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes after posting, I came up with my own answer. The vehicle code in `index.html.erb` should be:

```
<% for recall in @recalls.select(:vehicle).distinct.where(:recall_num => rn.recall_num) %>
  <%= recall.vehicle %><br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways you could do this, probably the quick 'n dirtiest way would be to change your vehicle block to something like the following:

```
<% vehicles = @recalls.where(:recall_num => rn.recall_num).pluck(:vehicle).uniq %>
<%= vehicles.join("<br>") %>
```

That said, a much more efficient approach would be to build a subquery such that you retrieve one clean resultset. I'd have to fiddle, but I would suggest trying squeel for this:

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#subqueries

Comment: I was writing up a solution I found at the same time that you posted. I'll look into the subquery suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modeling your data differently.  If a recall number is only going to have one description and type then you would probably be better off normalizing your data to avoid repetition in your database.

For example, you could move your Vehicles to their own separate table and then join each recall to the vehicles through another join table.  This could also save you a lot of headaches later on if you need to data maintenance like updating a description or vehicle name.

```
class Recall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recalled_vehicles
  has_many :vehicles, through: :recalled_vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class RecalledVehicles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recall
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

Here is a quick example of how that could work in a view

```
<% recall = Recall.find_by_recall_num(XXX) %>
<%= recall.description %><br />
<%= recall.type %><br />
<% recall.vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
<%= vehicle.name %><br />
<% end %>
```